# fixed the position for any resolution

Tags: jquery, html, css

My css part

```
html {
    background-image:url('Images/Site.jpg');

    background-repeat:no-repeat;


    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

}
#webform {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;

    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 7.5%;
    top: 40%;

}
```

My html part

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="webform" >


<form>bla bla bla </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my web [here](http://bluewingholidays.com/uthpala/index.php)

I want to fixed my form inside that image where it's called already( under the space of "how can i help you " ) ? how could i do this ?

[image]

Comment: If you really want to use CSS3, you need only one image for this design: the picture of the dude. I suggest you start from scratch, and maybe try to learn a thing or two.

Answer (score 2):

The way you're approaching this problem is why it's making it so difficult. You have a single background image containing your background, image, name, caption, and the select box. These should all be separately sliced, and in your HTML, positioned with CSS.

Instead of me answering your question, I'd advise that you go back into your design (be it in photoshop, gimp, or some other program), and slice everything up, placing each element into your html, and positioning it with CSS. That's how HTML markup works. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: i use background-cover property.i want to place my form under the how may i help you field.how i can do this ?

Comment: What I'm saying is that the `background-cover` property is a terrible idea for an image that has multiple parts. That shouldn't be needed. If the screen size is bigger, then the image will be bigger as well, and then you'll have to dynamically resize your "how may I help you" div as well, which means you're going to be writing some javascript for that. My advice, as I said before, is to go back, slice all these images up, place them with HTML and CSS, and learn how that all works. It'll be better in the long run.

Comment: Or how about not using background-images at all? The question is marked CSS3 which is completely capable of rendering this layout without a single image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want fixed positions, use fixed values, NOT PERCENTAGES.

Comment: it is changing when use different resolutions?

Comment: i used fixed .but same ....course i'm using background-cover property.i want to place my form to under the how can i help you.but i can't do it

Answer (score -1):

I see what you want to do, however you won't accomplish it using neither percentage of fixed values.....

You need to save the square around the form as a separeted image with transparent background and use this image as background of your form and not of the entire website.

```
#webform {
background-image:url(images/your_image.jpg);
padding: *;
}
```

*use the image dimensions from top, left, right and bottom of your bg image until it reaches the form.

Comment: why the hell someone voted my answer down?

Comment: this is wrong answer.i use background-cover property.i want to place my form under the how may i help you field.how i can do this ?

Comment: That's lovely, I try to help and instead of at least try to understand what I said you immediately vote my answer down. Do what James said and slice your website, or go study HTML.